# Inspecting Flutter app for automation testing

Tags: flutter, appium

I need to inspect a flutter app. I tried with Appium inspector with Flutter automationName.

I need to inspect a flutter app. I tried with Appium inspector with Flutter automationName. But, that didn’t work. As I researched I can use flutter Inspector. I’m not sure how to use it. It needs source code of app to inspect. In my case, developers are developing the app and provide apk file for testing via app tester. Tester we don’t have access to the source code. So, in this scenario, how can I use Flutter Inspector? Is it really possible tester to have the source code and inspect it? If tester have the code, then we need to update i for each release. Anyone if know the solution for this